# Azure Databricks - Receive error Zip bomb detected! The file would exceed the max. ratio of compressed file size to the size of the expanded data

Tags: maven, azure-databricks

I have been through many a links to solve this problem. However, none have helped me. Primarily because I am facing this error on Azure Databricks.

I am trying to read Excel files located on ADLS Curated zone. There are about 25 of the excel files. My program loops through the excel files and reads them into a PySpark Dataframe. However, after reading about 9 excel files, I receive the below error -

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1481.load.
: java.io.IOException: Zip bomb detected! The file would exceed the max. ratio of compressed file size to the size of the expanded data.
This may indicate that the file is used to inflate memory usage and thus could pose a security risk.
You can adjust this limit via ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() if you need to work with files which exceed this limit.
Uncompressed size: 6111064, Raw/compressed size: 61100, ratio: 0.009998
```

I installed the maven - org.apache.poi.openxml4j but when I try to call it using the simple following import statement, I receive the error "No module named 'org'"
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile

Any ideas anyone about how to set the ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() to 0 in Azure Databricks?

Best regards,
Sree

Comment: Anyone who can help me here?? Still very badly stuck at this. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

The "Zip bomb detected" exception will occur if the expanded file crosses the default MinInflateRatio set in the Apache jar. Apache includes a setting called MinInflateRatio which is configurable via ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() ; this will now be set to 0.0 by default to allow large files.

Checkout  known issue in POI: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58499

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: I am so sorry for the delay in response. I appreciate your response to my question. The concern is when I try to set the the config ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() to 0, I receive an error called ZipSecureFile not defined. I have installed the apache library for the same on my cluster too. I am using Python code in AZ Databricks. The main purpose of my question was to get an answer to how to define the ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() to 0. So yes, your answer is not exactly the solution to my problem.

Comment: @SreeNair Did you manage to resolve the issue? I am facing this same issue now. BTW were you using Pandas or Spark on Databricks?